# Should my team wait few weeks more before buying MSDN subscription after Studio 2010 release?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can one expect some promotional prices for MSDN subscriptions after release of MS Studio 2010 happened today on April 12? Or are the MSDN prices usually irrelevant to Studio releases?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the subscription price will not suddenly change at any given subscription level (it hasn't in the past, to my knowledge), just because VS2010 is coming out. But you would have to ask Microsoft if you want to be sure.

Comment: Thank you. That what I want to figure out, if there ever was a change in price relevant to releases.